# jquery selectors - select first three letters of class

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors, find

I have classes where the first 3 letters are the same

jobOne
 jobTwo
 jobThree

For example:

```
<div class="jobOne"></div>
<div class="jobTwo"></div>
<div class="jobThree"></div>
```

I want to match all classes that start with job. on a div.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the following, substituting div for the element of your choice:

```
$("div[class^='job']");
```

Also see the offical documentation: [attribute starts with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use jQuery attribute selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
$("div[class^='job']");
```

also you can loop threw all the matches by

```
$("div[class^='job']").each(function(){
   // do your coding using $(this)
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this Jquery doc : http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

```
jQuery('[class^="job"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

'HTML CODE'

```
  <div class="jobOne"></div>
  <div class="jobTwo"></div>
  <div class="jobThrees"></div>
```

'JS CODE'

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('div[class^="job"]'));
});
```

[**Have more idea from here**](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

Comment: @welovedesign is that working? Please inform if modification needed.